# findbug on intellij with scala and qaplugin "analyze current file is disabled"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, findbugs

I understand that findbugs "works" on classfiles.  However in my intellij I have `qaplugin` with `findbugs` and while all is fine with `java` files it is disabled for `scala` files, the option to `analyze current file` is disabled... am i missing something? I thought this should work also on scala files.

Comment: Have you tried FindBugs (outside IDEA) on Scala-generated bytecode? It's a bit, uh, noisy…